# What is chemical binding energy?

Tags: nuclear-physics, chemical-compounds

Like in nuclear physics we deal with binding energies, i heard someone saying Chemical binding energy. What is that and how a chemical reaction follows mass energy interconversion based on this concept like a nuclear reaction follows?

Answer (score 0):

Chemical binding energies are all to do with atoms being bound together and are of order of magnitude electron volts $(1 \rm eV \approx 1.6 \times 10^{-19} \rm J)$ whereas nuclear binding energies are order of magnitude a million times larger.  In chemistry it is usual to measure that quantity in terms of a mole of bonds rather than per one bond.
This means that the change in mass during a chemical reaction is a million times smaller than that for a nuclear reaction.